# Inherited control "locked"?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, controls

I have a series of forms that are inheriting control from a parent form. To manage space, I am trying to manoeuvre the controls around to make it a better layout on the child forms, however, certain controls appear to be "locked", indicated by a small lock symbol when the control is selected:

[image: labels are "locked"]

I am not sure what is causing this, as it only appears (in this case) to be happening to the labels, but not the text boxes. This is preventing me from editing any of the controls properties, (all of the properties window options have been disabled) meaning that I cannot change their locations. However this is not the case for the text boxes, or the groupboxes they came in.

How can I change this so that I can move them around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this is caused by the modifiers being set to "Private". Setting them to "Public" allows you to move them around on the child form freely.